# Android: Screen off - notifications delayed / blocking

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

This issue I have may be only present on devices running Oreo or later as I have only a OnePlus 3T with me for development.

I have a **foreground** `Service` that is started using `ContextCompat#startForegroundService()` and in the service's `startCommand` method I make sure to create / enable my **notification channel** so that I can call `startForeground` with the associated on-going notification.
So I believe, in terms of requirements I get everything right here.

What does my `Foreground Service` do:

- It acts as a **Bluetooth Server** using the Bluetooth Class RFCOMM BSPP to listen for client to connect ;
- When a client connects, it listens for incoming requests ;
- It performs the requests and send data accordingly.

My problem lies with the last point. When I connect and ask to send data, two things happen on the phone :

1. The relevant data is being loaded from the phone and
2. Once fully loaded, the data is sent to the client.

Each of these operations have their own notifications to display progress to the end-user.

While the first operation is not delayed, the second one may take many minutes (up to 6 in one of my tests).

After further tests, the cause is the notifications because I cancel the first operation notification then I call the second operation, which in turns will display and update its own notification.

So in the end, because I call `NotificationManagerCompat.cancel` on the first operation notification right before calling the second operation, that call can be delayed for a lot of time. If I don't cancel the notification first, then the second operation is immediately started.

As a solution, I believed that the Doze mode is responsible for that behavior, so I manually white-listed my app the battery optimisation settings of my phone. That did not change a single thing.

Finally, if, at any point, I unlock my phone / turn the screen on, the blocking / delaying notifications get's unlocked immediately and the second process starts right on the bat. So, of course, this behavior does not occur when my phone is plugged into my computer even with screen off.

Is this a bug ? Is this related to doze mode ? I do not know.

### **[Edit 1]**

For better clarity, here is a code snippet that represents the sequence of operations:

```
loadData() {
    ... // defer heavy work on a worker thread and updates notification of progress from time to time (every 10%)
    notifyDataLoadingStarted(); // on main thread. Displays its notification with progress bar   
}

// once the data is fully loaded
onDataLoaded() { // called on the main thread
    cancelDataLoadNotification();   // asks the notification manager compat to cancel notification
    initiateDataSendingOperation(); // will also defer heavy work on a worker thread and update its notification accordingly
}
```

What happens is that `onDataLoaded` is called once the first operation is over. But the problem is that `cancelDataLoadNotification` is blocking. I am on the main thread and this methods returns very very lately. Hence, this is the reason why `initiateDataSendingOperation` is greatly delayed.

When I unlock my phone, I could see that the notification of the loading operation is stuck in the middle, as though the loading operation is halted, around 50%. However, this only lasts a fraction of a second because before I know it, the first notification pops out while the the second notification pops in. All in the blink of an eye. Which clearly means that yes, the first operation was indeed over since a long time ago, but its notification was definitely obsolete. And since the second operation would only be initiated when the first notification is cancelled, they you can clearly understand that the second operation is greatly delayed.

That's why my first workaround works if I first start the second operation before canceling the first operation notification.

**Nevertheless, in any case, the notifications are still out of date while screen is off.**

Comment: Just to understand. Why do you cancel the first notification instead of just replacing it with the new one, sending  a new notification with the same id? And another doubt: is the operation delayed or the showing of the notification?

Comment: @kingston thanks for your comment. You have a good point, however I have two specific notifications (with unique ID): one for data loading, one for data sending. At the current stage, loading and sending are sequential operations but it is possible in the futur everything can be paralleled. In short, I might very well be loading some data while sending other (previously loaded) data. That's why there are two notifications. In any case, regardless of operations order, once an operation ends, it's notification is cancelled. But when screen is off, the `notificationManager` is blocked / delayed.

Comment: @kingston Anyway, as a workaround, I first call the sending operation before cancelling the notification of the first operation. This is what made me understand that the `notificationManagerCompat` was blocking / delaying the execution block. In the end, all operations would occur but no notifications update / cancellation would occur in the process. **Is that intended behavior ?**

Comment: No as far as I know. I'm working on an app that shows notifications and works with services in the background and I do not have problems. Another doubt: are you sure that when you cancel the notification the service that you started with `startForegroundService` is terminated? Otherwise, the app would crash on Android 8+. Unless of course you always show a notification.

Comment: @kingston the foreground service is indeed running after calling `startForegroundService` with the "main" notification as explained in OP's introduction. I don't use the service's notification for anything else than notify of current bluetooth server state : idle or connected. The other notifications are issued from the foreground service and they belong to a same group and notification channel as well (to be compliant with Android 8+). While making my tests, this foreground service is not crashed. And as I said, the moment I turn on the screen, the notifications immediately pop in!

Comment: @kingston I have added an import edit and the end of my OP which should clarify some points. I hope it will make my problem more understandable.